# Использование path() в Django 2.0

Tags: python, django, path

Ниже написан код в `Django 1.11`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.home, name='home'), #ссылка на http://localhost:8000
    url(r'^landing/', views.landing, name='landing'), #ссылка на http://localhost:8000/landing
]
```

Каким должен быть этот код в `Django 2.0`? Имеется в виду использование `path()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как будет выглядеть это, ответил Артём.

А как использовать его, вот:

```
# До Django 2.0
urlpatterns = [
    url('^test/(?P<number>[0-9]*)$', views.test, name='test'),
    url('^test/', views.page, name="page")
]

# Django 2.0
urlpatterns = [
    path('test/<int:testvar>', views.test, name='test'),
    path('page/', views.page, name="page")
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.home, name='home'), 
path('landing/', views.landing, name='landing'),
]
```